# What exactly mean the PACKAGE keyword into a sh\bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I am pretty new in sh\bash scripting.

In a script on which I have to do some refactoring operation I found these 2 lines of code:

```
cp -Rf PACKAGE $HOME/connect-data-space${CURRENT_VERSION}ubuntu1-i386
cp -Rf PACKAGE $HOME/connect-data-space${CURRENT_VERSION}ubuntu1-amd64
```

Reading the cp command documentation I have found that R mean that the operation is recursively on directories and files in the directory on which I am calling and that f means that can force the copy.

But what exactly mean **PACKAGE** before the directory name? I can't find information about it

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: It means nothing, it's cp argument. A name of file or directory to be copied.

Comment: To add to what @Grzegorz said, it's a file/directory.

Comment: mmm and what it means?

Comment: ah so it copied it into a file named PACKAGE?

Comment: It copies the file (or directory?) `PACKAGE` to the destination.

Comment: Type `man cp` at your shell prompt. This will show you the documentation for the `cp` command.

Answer (score 0):

It has *no* special significance. The command:

```
cp -Rf PACKAGE /somewhere_else
```

will simply copy (recursively, and with forced replacement if need be) the file system object `PACKAGE` (in the current directory) to the `/somewhere_else` directory.